# Can I still use Rules to send "CC:" emails or am I going to have to do everything as a custom module?

Tags: rules, emails

I am currently using the Rules module along with workbench to determine when to send an email and this is working fine.
The problem is now the client wants to in addition to sending email to the "To:" (which is working fine) and also to the "CC:" section which does not seem to be configurable with the Rules since they only have a "To:" section and not a "CC:".
Can I still use Rules to send "CC:" emails or am I going to have to do everything as a custom module?

Comment: Even if you have to make a custom module, you can always extend the Rules "Send mail" action to add "CC:", which would be much easier than doing everything in a custom module.

Comment: You can duplicate the rule and use **To** field for **CC** emails

Comment: how will it know that the "To" field is for CC emails?